# running user-defined modules from a central directory

Tags: python-3.x

I am a beginner in python. I am using python 3.7 via anaconda. I have made certain modules that I want to re-use by importing them in python scripts. Is there a way to centrally store all my modules in one directory and import them when needed?

My actual python scripts may be in different project directories but I want the importable user-defined modules to be stored in a central directory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a virtual environment for maintaining packages for a project.Create a requirement.txt file from virtulenv and installback when needed.

```
pip install virtualenv
```

you should activate virtual env before using it.

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Read about virtualenv here [https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/1.7.1.2/#:~:text=You%20can%20install%20virtualenv%20with,it%20with%20python%20virtualenv.py](https://pypi.org/project/virtualenv/1.7.1.2/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20install%20virtualenv%20with,it%20with%20python%20virtualenv.py).

Relative import method for your modules:
change your working directory and import modules.

```
import os
os. chdir('your docs folder path')
from your_modules import *
from module2 import *
```

add your folder to sys path:

```
import sys
import os.path
sys.path.append(
    os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), os.path.pardir)))

import yourmodule
```

Comment: I feel virtual env may not help since i am not having any package as such to import. All I am having is a few modules which i have made. I want to import these modules into my scripts. The problem is u have to copy all the modules into the directory of the script if u want to import them. Is there an option to centrally store the modules maybe in Documents folder and then import them?

Comment: Check this in the answer : Relative import method for your modules

Comment: Thanks. Once I do os.chdir("module folder"), then if I have to import datafile from my project script directory, do I need to again do os.chdir to revert back to my project directory

Comment: If you want are saving anyfiles in project directory, you need to go back or else no need of changing the directory back. Please mark the answer as solved.

Comment: Pardon for asking, is there any other way other than os.chdir(), like specifying a folder as a package folder  or copying the user-defined modules into site package directory and then importing from there. I am only a novice. So pls bear.

Comment: check this part "add your folder to path" in answer, this is another way of doing the same.